# the owner of files in 13.04

Tags: installation, permissions, 13.04

Why is the owner of files set to a user called "Me" in 13.04 beta 2 64bit live desktop and also after install? After installation, it also won't let me change the permissions as root or take ownership away from user "Me" Even if I create a new user. Anyone help?

I never created a user called "Me".

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean when you say it won't let you? What have you tried, and what has happened, exactly? (Please expand your question by editing it, to add this information. Thanks.)

Comment: So when you `ls -l` it shows 'Me' in the third and fourth columns?

Answer (score 4):

If you are inferring to the **ME** part when in Nautilus and you select Permission for a file/folder, then this **Me** is simply a short way of saying your username. As seen on this image:

[image]

It is a simple way of showing the name. It means that in this case, the owner is you. In regards to creating another user and trying to take over files/folders from your other user, this will not work except if you use the `chmod` and/or `chown` commands on it. As a matter of fact, if you created the other user, when you go into this user's home folder and see the permission on any of the files, you will also see **ME** as the owner, in this case implying that me is the other user.